# Get Device Aspect Ratio for Windows Store App in Background Process

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm running a background process (WindowsRuntimeComponent) and need to know the device (PC or Tablet) Aspect Ratio for cropping an image to fit the Lock Screen background. Is there a way to do this, seeing that it's a background process with nothing rendered on screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the required sizes

```
var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
double height = bounds.Height;
double width = bounds.Width;
```

Though while working with store app I found the following code to be working better as it adjust according to resolution

```
var width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width * (int)DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale / 100;
var height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height * (int)DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale / 100; 
var dpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawDpiY; 
var screenDiagonal = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(width / dpi, 2) +Math.Pow(height / dpi, 2));
```

Comment: I get a null reference exception for Windows.Current. Probably because it's a background process and there is no Windows.Current associated with it.